# Can't load db functions in error_404 page codeignigter 3.1.9

Tags: codeigniter

I wanted to show my website image icon from database and use it for 404 error tab (like how I used it for other pages on my website) but I receive warning massage like this:

Undefined property: CI_Exceptions::$db

I don't understand the reason behind it.
I appreciate if someone helps me to solve my problem.

```
<?php

    $this -> db -> limit ( 1 );
    $this -> db -> order_by('id','desc');
    if ($query = $this->db->get('settings')->result()) {
        $logo_img = $query[0]->logo_img;
    }

?>
```

I wanted last logo_img and this is how I load it for other pages but when I use it for **application/views/errors/html/error_404.php** it shows this error that shows up for every kind of code that starts with
`$this->`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your autoload yet? In ../application/config/autoload.php there is a code like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('');
```

You can change it to

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```